# Unable to append items in value array of mutable dictionary

Tags: dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: @{ @"Maruti":@[@"m1",@"m2"], @"Hyundai":@[@"h1",@"h2"] } ];
```

How can I add values in value array of each key so that my output would look like:

```
Maruti:[m1,m2,m3] Hyundai:[h1,h2,h3]
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Both Maruti and hyundai dictionary are NSDictionary so you cannot add any new values into them , plus you cannot use any of them outside of the scope of this method, but if you still want to do something like this you can go with this.

```
NSMutableDictionary * tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [tempDict setValue:@"5" forKey:@"number"];
    [tempDict setValue:@"6" forKey:@"Hidden"];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [tempDict setValue:@"5" forKey:@"number"];
    [tempDict setValue:@"6" forKey:@"Hidden"];
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [mutableDict setValue:tempDict forKey:@"Dict 1"];
    [mutableDict setValue:tempDict2 forKey:@"Dict 2"];
```